# I am having some problems checking the winner in a tic tac toe game using Turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, tic-tac-toe

```
def isWinner (square) :
    (square[0] and square[1] and square[2])
    (square[3] and square[4] and square[5]) 
    (square[6] and square[7] and square[8]) 
    (square[0] and square[3] and square[6]) 
    (square[1] and square[4] and square[7]) 
    (square[2] and square[5] and square[8]) 
    (square[0] and square[4] and square[8]) 
    (square[2] and square[4] and square[6])
```

This is as far as I have come but I do not really know were to go from here.
Any help at all would be aprecciated. :)

Comment: where is your if statement? Are you checking if all these are True? where is your return statement. Can you provide more details of the isWinner function. Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to send the list `square` to the function `isWinner` and want to check if the tic-tac-toe values match on rows or columns or diagonal.

To do this, you need to change the function as follows:

```
def isWinner (square):
    if (square[0] == square[1] == square[2]) \
    or (square[3] == square[4] == square[5]) \
    or (square[6] == square[7] == square[8]) \
    or (square[0] == square[3] == square[6]) \
    or (square[1] == square[4] == square[7]) \
    or (square[2] == square[5] == square[8]) \
    or (square[0] == square[4] == square[8]) \
    or (square[2] == square[4] == square[6]):
        return True
    else: return False
```

Assumption here is that square is a list or dictionary and the values in the index or key value represents a `O` or `X`.

A few examples:

```
print ('''0,0,0
X,0,X
X,X,X''')
print (isWinner(['0','0','0','X','0','X','X','X','X']))
print ('''X,0,0,
X,0,X,
X,0,X''')
print (isWinner(['X','0','0','X','0','X','X','0','X']))
print ('''X,0,0,
0,X,X,
X,0,0''')
print (isWinner(['X','0','0','0','X','X','X','0','0']))
```

Output:

```
#last row has all X. Result = True
0,0,0
X,0,X
X,X,X
True

#first column has all X, so is second column with all 0. Result = True
X,0,0,
X,0,X,
X,0,X
True

#no match row wise, column wise, or diagonal. Result = False
X,0,0,
0,X,X,
X,0,0
False
```